# Android: synchronization of Audio, images and text in a Media Player,

Tags: android, image, synchronization, mp3

I would like to know how I can synchronize an mp3 file, a text box and images (mp3, text and images must be received via http) that is will be displayed on a video player which must receive and show the images every 10 seconds, and likewise have a text box with the synchronized audio and therefore with the images (showing the text of the mp3), I have researched, but i not know where to start, how to manage the intervals and the data, with methods as "timer" in c #, really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the text and the images have TimeStamps associated with them. (TimeStamps - Time at which they should be displayed relative to the audio), if so then you can do this

- Play the audio file using the `MediaPlayer` class
- Use the method `getCurrentPosition()` to get the time value
- Based on the time above check if you need to update the image or the text or both, if you need to then update `TextView` and `ImageView`

Comment: Images and text does not have timestamps, i want to do this: https://www.mariposatraining.com/Classes/014-99d5bc44-73e3-4188-8bfe-4fc0e8529515/Presentation.htm, but for android UI, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: okay, re read your question. My suggestion about using `MediaPlayer` class to play the audio still stands. Since you need to change the image at regular intervals of 10 mins, use the `Timer` class to get events for every 10 mins, or you can write delayed messages to your handler. Once you get the event then switch the image and text

Answer (score 0):

Check out the CountDownTimer class provided in the android sdk to manage the intervals: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

As for getting images via http here is a simple java tutorial on sockets: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that with:

```
if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && abc >= 313800 && abc < 379340){
            currentimageindex=6;
            subtitles.setText(this.getString(R.string.t7));
```

I hope to help others.